# Could someone, anyone, help me rebuild my RAID 10 array please?

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid, synology-diskstation, raid-10

A little background information just to help (hopefully)... I was doing a backup from my Synology box over the weekend and all was going very well up until Sunday morning when I've tried to re-connect my backup server to copy over some data via my 10Gb network. For some reason, it would only work at 1Gb speeds so I thought I'll restart my devices and see if that works. Well that made it worse. From then on, it would throw up an error in Windows to say that I couldn't access the shared folders (I could see them still) but I couldn't get to any of the data.

[image: Windows error trying to access Synology]

So fast forwarding on a little, I then started a little research and found that installing Ubuntu would allow it to read the data and I could hopefully start recovering it.

[image: A working RAID 10 array]

Fast forward a little more, it did and worked fine. But then disaster struck and for some reason, it stopped copying and said there was an error and the array had disappeared. The RAID array, is a RAID 10, consisting of 8 x 8TB drives.

In a panic, I'd removed the drives as if I remember correctly a couple had disappeared from the list.
After checking each one, I found that what I thought was a non working SATA port on the motherboard. Turned out, it was nothing of worry. So frustrating.

Fast forward again. I've noticed when looking back at my screen shots, that the device numbers are all in the wrong order. They should have been -

SDF3 0 SDD3 7 SDE3 6 SDC3 5 SDB3 4 SDI3 3 SDH3 2 SDG3 1

Currently they are -

SDE3 6 SDD3 7 SDI3 2 SDH3 3 SDG3 5 SDF3 4 SDB3 1 SDC3 0

[image: A none working RAID 10 array]

Now I've tried moving the data cables around and seeing if that changes the list which is does but as I figured, unless its in the arrangement above, its not going to work?

I have managed to do a few commands with mdadm --examine and I think I have grabbed the info data from each drive after reading another post back sometime ago from ServerFault.

When I have tried re-assembling the array, it errors saying that "Cannot assemble MBR metadata on /dev/sdb (I presume it needs to be SDF3 ??)

When I have tried these drives again in the Synology box, it still gives me the same error, so I hope, that the data is still intact on the drives.

If there is anything else you need from me, please don't hesitate to let me know. I will do my best and I'm trying to learn Ubuntu as I go, so apologies if I'm daft and slow! I do have the terminal text saved, but I can't see a way to add in the file, could someone please advise how to?
Massive thanks in advance.

EDIT - Drive array details

[image: Raid 10 Array Details]

As far as I can see, the SDD3 and SDE3 drives have the 603 errors.  The rest - SDB3. SDC3, SDF3, SDG3, SDH3 and SDI3 have 607 errors.
Each drive shows the array there still, at this point I feel hopeful...

Was there anything else you gents required?

EDIT Some more group screen shots -

[image: More RAID 10 Array details]

[image: Some additional information]

[image: ![Some more additional information]

Apologises Brian for the delay in getting this information..  I believe I've used the commands as expected?

mdadm --assemble --readonly /dev/[md2] [dev/md2 /dev/sdb3 /dev/sdc3 /dev/sdd3 /dev/sde3 /dev/sdf3 /dev/sdg3 /dev/sdh3 /dev/sdi3]
dd if=/dev/[All drives] skip=1000000000000 bs=1M count=10 | sha256sum

In the screen shot, it mentions

dadm: cannot open device [dev/md2: No such file or directory
mdadm: [dev/md2 has no superblock - assembly aborted

But says in the detail, that a superblock is persistent.  I'm a little confused...

Another update Brian....

[image: 25-07-23 Drive information]
[image: 25-07-23 Sorted drive info]

A massive thank you's goes out to Brian....

[image: Ta da!! Working array!!]

Without the help from Brian, this would have never been possible.  Massive thanks again!!  Respect and knowledge +100 for you sir!!

Comment: @Phill - You’ll want to edit your question and upload your images using the image function within the editor instead of linking to your private Imgur images. If you removed drives while the RAId was rebuilding you can consider your data toast. Combine images into a single image to by pass the image link limitation plus it will make it easier to read later providing you proper crop the images to reasonable sizes.

Comment: So by looking at the results Brian I posted above, we need to match the drives with the same 'number' so example - SDC3 ends with ec79d9 and the other that does that is SDG3??  If that's the case, I've matched them up in the last screen grab, as its nearing 1am, I just wished to get this done before I get to sleep for a few hours before work! :D  I hope this is correct :)

Comment: This looks good. Since /dev/sdb3 and /dev/sdc3 are the removed drives but their mirrored disks remain online, the array should reassemble without a problem. So, if you aren't worry by data loss, we can try taking steps to bring everything back online. 1. `mdadm --assemble /dev/md2 /dev/sdd3 /dev/sde3 /dev/sdf3 /dev/sdg3 /dev/sdh3 /dev/sdi3`; 2. `mdadm --re-add /dev/md2 /dev/sdb3`; 3. `mdadm --re-add /dev/md2 /dev/sdc3`. Wait about 5 minutes and take a shot of `cat /proc/mdstat` to see the status of the array. Also post, `mdadm --detail /dev/md2`.

Comment: If we are comfortable with the array being back together based on the results of `cat /proc/mdstat` and `mdadm --detail /dev/md2`, we can take the following two steps. 1. `mdadm --stop /dev/md2`; 2. `mdadm --assemble --run --force --update=resync /dev/md2 /dev/sdb3 /dev/sdc3 /dev/sdd3 /dev/sde3 /dev/sdf3 /dev/sdg3 /dev/sdh3 /dev/sdi3`. Wait about 5 minutes and again take a shot of `cat /proc/mdstat` to see the status of the array. Also post, `mdadm --detail /dev/md2`. Then you can mount the array `mount /dev/md2 [mount point]`

Comment: **NOTE: The commands in the above two comments can lead to irreversible changes. Be sure to either backup your drives or be willing to lose data in the event the above commands do not produced expected results**

Comment: To clone a drive you would do one of the following. If the disk were the identical (to the byte) size of the source disk: `dd if=/dev/[source] of=/dev/[target] bs=512K status=progress` (without brackets. If you were to clone it to a file to a drive larger than the source (and mounted itself: `dd if=/dev/[source] of=/[targetPath]/[targetFile].dd bs=512K status=progress` (not including brackets). (example: `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/media/usb/backup/sda1.dd bs=512K status=progress`. The `.dd` file extension is also optimal but I find it helps ensure you remember what the file is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Backup RAW Disks**

---

Before attempting any repairs on a damages `mdadm` array, it is strongly encouraged that you image the affected disks. If something goes awry while attempting to repair the array, you can always restore the images and start again. Basically, there is no-hard, no-foul if your attempted repair goes wrong.

Alternatively, if you proceed without imaging your disks, you should be prepared for irrecoverable data should something go wrong. All `mdadm` repairs are unique is there is not a guaranteed solution.

---

**One Way to Image Disks**

---

1. On a backup disk of the exact same size:

   - `dd if=/dev/[source disk] of=/dev/[backup disk] bs=512K status=progress`
2. On a backup disk larger than the source disk:

   - `dd if=/dev/[source disk] of=/[path to backup location]/[backup file].dd bs=512K status=progress`

---

**If You Need to Restore Imaged Disk**

---

1. On a backup disk of the exact same size:

   - `dd if=/dev/[backup disk] of=/dev/[source disk] bs=512K status=progress`
2. On a backup disk larger than the source disk:

   - `dd if=/[path to backup location]/[backup file].dd of=/dev/[source disk] bs=512K status=progress`

---

### Restoring Failed RAID 10 Array

---

In this specific case, the two of eight drives that failed were not mirrors of one another. Rather, they were mirrored disks of two other disks in the array that reported healthy. This is how we determined this

---

**Determining If Underlying Array Is Still Healthy**

---

In order to determine the role the two failed (or rather, removed) drives play was to sample the payload data of all the drives and attempt to match them up using their checksum hash values. This was accomplished with the following command on each disk in the array.

- `dd if=/dev/[source disk] bs=1M count=10 skip=1000000 | sha256sum`

This command takes a 10MB sample at the 1TB location of the drive and produces a checksum value for the data. We then compared the checksums to matchup all the drives (i.e. source with mirror). In this case, we were able to conclude that the two removed disks were not mirrors of each other and therefore the RAID 10 was effectively still intact.

---

**Repairing the Raid 10 Array**

---

1. Assemble the existing "healthy" array members (i.e. those that have not been removed).

   `mdadm --assemble /dev/[mdadm array] /dev/[disk 1] /dev/[disk 2] ... /dev/[disk N]`
2. Re-add the missing disks

   `mdadm --re-add /dev/[mdadm array] /dev/[missing disk 1]`

   `mdadm --re-add /dev/[mdadm array] /dev/[missing disk 2]`
3. Restart and Resync Array

   `mdadm --assemble --run --force --update=resync /dev/[mdadm array] /dev/[disk 1] /dev/[disk 2] ... /dev/[re-added disk 1] /dev/[re-added disk 2]`

---

**Check to See if Raid is Rebuilding**

---

Now to want to check to see if the RAID is rebuilding. To do this, check to the following two things.

1. Run `cat /proc/mdstat` to see if it indicates the RAID is being rebuilt.
2. Run `mdadm --detail /dev/[mdadm array]` to see if all members are part of the array and it is rebuiding.

If it is not reassembled correctly and rebuilding, you need addition troubleshooting support to repair you failed array. Remember all failures are not the same.